# Implementing custom syntax for JavaScript or another language

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm looking on how I could create custom syntax for a language such as JavaScript that seemingly doesn't allow you to do that.

As a basic example, what if I would want to create this kind of syntax for JavaScript:

```
cout <<< "Text";
```

And this custom syntax would be converted to this:

```
cout("Text");
```

From what I understand you cannot implement that in JavaScript itself. So a solution I've been thinking about is that instead, I will type all my JavaScript code in a text file and then run a program that would;

- Take the text file as input
- Skim through all the text searching for lines that have 'cout' in them
- Somehow make sure that the text is not actually in a string or something, maybe just check for 'cout' in the beginning of the line - not really sure on this part.
- Split the text, find the correct part, and replace the custom syntax part with the function.
- Once done, create a new .js file that has the "compiled" normal syntax code.

I believe that it is also what the CSS extension Sass does? I'm asking this question because I want to know if there is some better or perhaps even a built-in way to do what I'm trying to achieve. And the actual custom syntax that I'm trying to create is more complex than the example I provided.

Comment: You would clash with the left shift operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to write a "transpiler". This is just a compiler that reads code written in your own syntax and outputs legal JavaScript code which performs the same tasks.

To follow this approach, you don't skim through the code finding the pieces that you have defined in your own language. Rather, you parse the entire file and emit equivalent JavaScript code. For standard JavaScript, you just emit it directly. For your custom code, you emit the equivalent JavaScript code.